# How to set word wrap strategy on a google sheets api using the java library

Tags: java, android, google-sheets-api

Worked on this awhile, saw some things that were close on stack overflow but nothing that had a good example with context.  My big issue was getting the gridId for the sheet.

```
final Request wrap = new Request()
                .setRepeatCell(new RepeatCellRequest()
                        .setCell(new CellData()
                                // test to see what field gets set
                                // .setUserEnteredValue( new ExtendedValue().setStringValue(mContext.getString(R.string.lazy_dog)))
                                .setUserEnteredFormat(new CellFormat().setWrapStrategy("WRAP")))
                        .setRange(new GridRange()
                                .setSheetId(response.getSheets().get(0).getProperties().getSheetId())
                                .setStartRowIndex(2)
                                .setStartColumnIndex(1)
                                .setEndColumnIndex(2)
                        ).setFields("*")
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the entire code block that worked for me.  I am sure there are more concise ways to do it.  Any input is welcome, but this worked for me.  the code is in a task, only the parts that create a new sheet, add the columns and formatting are included.

```
 SpreadsheetProperties properties = new SpreadsheetProperties();
    properties.setTitle(new StringBuilder(mContext.getString(R.string.app_initials))
            .append(" " + mUnit)
            .append(" ")
            .append(calendar.getTime().toString())
            .toString());

    Spreadsheet requestBody = new Spreadsheet();

    GridProperties gridProperties = new GridProperties();
    gridProperties.setFrozenRowCount(2).setColumnCount(7);

    SheetProperties sheetProperties = new SheetProperties();
    sheetProperties.setTitle("my new sheet");
    sheetProperties
            .setGridProperties(gridProperties);

    Sheet sheet = new Sheet();
    sheet.setProperties(sheetProperties);

    List<Sheet> sheets = new ArrayList<>();
    sheets.add(sheet);

    requestBody.setSheets(sheets);
    requestBody.setProperties(properties);

    String rangeH = "A1:D1";

    List<List<Object>> valuesH = new ArrayList<>();
    Object o1 = "date", o2 = "description", o3 = "distance", o4 = "total " + mUnit, o5 = "", o6 = "total time";
    valuesH.add(Arrays.asList(o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6));

    ValueRange valueRangeH = new ValueRange();
    valueRangeH.setMajorDimension("ROWS");
    valueRangeH.setRange(rangeH);
    valueRangeH.setValues(valuesH);

    //Object formula = "=SUM(C1:C)";
    String range = "D2:F2";

    Object o7 = "=SUM(C1:C)", o8 = mUnit, o9 = "=SUM(F3:F)";

    List<List<Object>> values = new ArrayList<>();

    values.add(Arrays.asList(o7, o8,o9));

    ValueRange valueRange = new ValueRange();
    valueRange.setMajorDimension("ROWS");
    valueRange.setRange(range);
    valueRange.setValues(values);

    Spreadsheet response = null;
    AppendValuesResponse avResponse = null;

    try {

        Sheets.Spreadsheets.Create request = mService.spreadsheets().create(requestBody);
        response = request.execute();

        avResponse = this.mService.spreadsheets().values()
                .append(response.getSpreadsheetId(), rangeH, valueRangeH)
                .setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED")
                .execute();

        //adds the formula
        avResponse = this.mService.spreadsheets().values()
                .append(response.getSpreadsheetId(), range, valueRange)
                .setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED")
                .execute();

        final Request wrap = new Request()
                .setRepeatCell(new RepeatCellRequest()
                        .setCell(new CellData()
                                // test to see what field gets set
                                // .setUserEnteredValue( new ExtendedValue().setStringValue(mContext.getString(R.string.lazy_dog)))
                                .setUserEnteredFormat(new CellFormat().setWrapStrategy("WRAP")))
                        .setRange(new GridRange()
                                .setSheetId(response.getSheets().get(0).getProperties().getSheetId())
                                .setStartRowIndex(2)
                                .setStartColumnIndex(1)
                                .setEndColumnIndex(2)
                        ).setFields("*")
                );


        List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        requests.add(wrap);




      this.mService.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(response.getSpreadsheetId(),
                new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest().setRequests(requests))
                .execute();
```